# Vimscript: Error while checking for substring

Tags: vim, gvim, vimscript

I am currently trying to tie together a function to do something depending on current file path, triggered whenever I change the current buffer with **autocmd BufEnter**

In my .vimrc

```
autocmd BufEnter * call SayLocation()
```

Further down in my .vimrc

```
fun SayLocation()
  let str = expand("%p:~")

  if str =~ "~/dir1"
    echo "I am in dir 1!"

  elseif str =~ "~/dir2"
    echo "I am in dir 2!"

  else 
    echo "I am somewhere else"

  endif
endf
```

However, changing the buffer yields the following error

Line 3:
**E33: No previous substitute regular expression**
Line 7:
**E33: No previous substitute regular expression**
I am somewhere else

It seems I am running the substring comparator =~ wrong. Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **escape** the `~` character:

```
if str =~ '\~/dir1'
```

The `:help E33` already explains the problem very well:

> E33 No previous substitute regular expression
>
> When using the '~' character in a pattern, it is replaced with the previously
>   used pattern in a ":substitute" command.  This fails when no such command has
>   been used yet.  See |/~|.  This also happens when using ":s/pat/%/", where the
>   "%" stands for the previous substitute string.

#### Additional critique

- You probably want to *anchor* the match to the beginning: `str =~ '^\~/dir1'`. Probably also assert a path separator at the end: `str =~ '^\~dir1/`, or else `~/dir10/file` would also be counted as inside `dir1`!
- The `=~` match operator (like the literal `==` comparison) obeys the `'ignorecase'` setting. Therefore, it is advisable to make the comparison independent of that option's current value via either `=~#` or `=~?`.
- Unless you need to use special key-notation, it's better to use single-quoted `'string'`, because the backslash has no special meaning there and doesn't need to be escaped (once more).
- You should wrap your `:autocmd` in an `:augroup`; without it, each reload of `~/.vimrc` will add another run:

```
augroup SayLocation
    autocmd! " Clear existing
    autocmd BufEnter * ...
augroup END
```

Comment: It seems I missed a tiny truckload of things haha, thanks a bunch :) The pattern is recognized now and that's all good and jolly, but it seems the function runs twice at every Buffer change :S Happen to have any pointers?

Comment: Did you reload your .vimrc? Better use an `:augroup`; I've added that to my answer.

Comment: That did the trick. You're awesome. Thanks again!